# python gnutella programming

Tags: python, p2p

I wanna learn how to build a p2p application in python that conforms to the gnutella protocol so it can tap-in the existing network like limewire, etc.

Any body who knows something where to start or a ste-by-step guide? I've been reading the http://wiki.limewire.org/index.php?title=GDF but I need something with an example so I can easily follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: **read the [protocol specification](http://rfc-gnutella.sourceforge.net/src/rfc-0_6-draft.html) carefully**

There are multiple python Gnutella implementations, I was able to find at least the following with quick googling:
[Quack](http://quack.sourceforge.net/), [gnuppy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuppy/). Check their source code for reference.

The python modules you might find helpful with protocol packet decoding and message parsing are [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) and [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). You might also need to implement some sort of [Finite State Machine](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146262/) to keep track of various exchanges.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. I think I need to understand very well the protocol first, only then will I appreciate the code.